# connecting to a domain controller / when logging into computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, dns, domain

When I am login into my computer, I can see that it is joined to a domain ->
`company.local`

So I am thinking well, `company.local` will be resolvable by an internal DNS to a domain controller's IP, so my computer will go there, try to login, get its necessary policies and privileges etc.

However, when I logout and log back in, I realize I do not need to specify the fullname of the domainname (e.g. `company.local`),  all I need is to just specify
`company\myusername`,   (I do not need to specify `company.local\username`
and I will be still able to connect to the DC.

How is `company` alone resolvable to an DC's IP?

Am I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If the computer is connected to a domain then it is enough to use your username. Normally the Primary DNS suffix will be set to company.local (or whatever the domain name is) and as such all DNS resolution will try to resolve the DNS request adding the primary suffix. That said, you have to bear in mind that there should be more than one DC, and that authentication will be handled also by the subnet/site settings. That means that a ping to the company name can resolve to different IPs. And (with default settings) you will be able to login to a PC even without being on a network after the first successful login while connected to the network (cached credentials). To get more information you should get familiar with AD, DNS, sites/subnets,... The Microsoft Technet site will be useful. But let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: where is the primary dns suffix being set ? in the client PC ? or at the DNS server ?

Comment: You can set it at the client level (which would be inefficient with the increasing number of clients) or push the settings through a DHCP server or push the setting through group policy.

Comment: in the client tcp/ip settings under DNS,   i saw this  "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes"   --> what does this means ?

Answer (score 1):

"Company" is the netbios name of that domain.

If you ever installed and setup windows it works kinda the same way, it will ask for a full fqdn and a netbios name.

Comment: in that case, when i specify "company\username"  without using "company.local\username"  -> "company" is resolve using NETBIOS or DNS ?

Comment: Correct it's netbios

Comment: how do i verify if it is really netbios ? can i have a wireshark / packet tracer running in background before logging on into the system ?